# Ubuntu vs. Red Hat errors

Tags: c, ubuntu, redhat

I have a C code which successfully runs under ubuntu, but when I am trying to run it on a red hat PC it is giving a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I have narrowed down the error to be from the following statement:

```
long int encryption[800000][2];
```

this declaration is causing the code to crash.

What can I do? Any suggesstions?
cheers =)

Comment: 1.6 million pointers. That's quite a bit.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: quite a few bits, 12.2 MiB actually (assuming 64bit pointers). Not too spectacular

Comment: @cwallenpoole: No, 1.6 million `long int`s and exactly 0 pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
static long int encryption[800000][2];
```

Or make it global, or use `malloc`.

Or use `ulimit -s`.

Comment: i changed it to static long and it worked, however the function in which this was used is multithreaded so I had to remove the multithreading.
any other way I can solve it without going global?
thanks

Comment: If you need a distinct copy of the array for each call to the containing function, use `malloc()` and `free()`.  (That might also give you an opportunity to allocate only what you need rather than the full 1.6 million `long int`s.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Sensible advice.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a stack overflow because the array is allocated on the stack.

The size of the stack is platform defined, depends on the threading model and configuration, and on `sysctl`/`ulimit` settings (among others?).

Make the array dynamically allocated or statically allocated ('global') to prevent this